# Do I need to override the Magento Core Files in order to create a new Admin Theme with a responsive design?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, theme, rwd

If I want to create a new theme for Magento 1.9.1 admin panel (with responsiveness), will I need to override core files?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.  The Theme layering system works similarly in the Admin back-end as it does on the front-end.

First, and foremost, you shouldn't modify ANY of the core theme files that ship with Magento.  Ever.  It's important enough to repeat because if you DO and you install an upgrade to Magento at a later date, at BEST you'll have to re-implement your changes after the update over-writes them.  You should ALWAYS start a custom theme project by create a new folder structure from scratch or worst case, copying the default theme folder you wish to duplicate and then store that copy in a separate folder from the original.

If you're combining it with a custom front-end theme, then you can create a new folder structure that would look something like this (it's not complete but should give you an idea of the correct way to approach the problem)

```
 webroot
 |--app
 |  \--design
 |    |--adminhtml
 |    |   |--default
 |    |   |   \--default
 |    |   |       |--etc
 |    |   |       |--layout
 |    |   |       |--locale
 |    |   |       \--template
 |    |   |
 |    |   \--your-new-theme
 |    |       \--default
 |    |           |--etc
 |    |           |--layout
 |    |           |--locale
 |    |           \--template
 |    |   
 |     \--frontend
 |        |
 |        |--base
 |        |   \--default
 |        |       |--etc
 |        |       |--layout
 |        |       |--locale
 |        |        \--template
 |        |
 |        |--rwd
 |        |   \--default
 |        |       |--etc
 |        |       |--layout
 |        |       |--locale
 |        |       \--template
 |        |
 |        \--your-new-theme
 |            \--default
 |                |--etc
 |                |--layout
 |                |--locale
 |                \--template
 |
 \--skin
 |    |--adminhtml
 |    |   |--default
 |    |   |   \--default
 |    |   |
 |    |   \--your-new-theme
 |    |       \--default
 |    |   
 |    |--frontend
 |    |   |--default
 |    |   |   \--default
 |    |   |
 |    |   \--your-new-theme
 |    |   |   \--default
```

Again, that's incomplete but it should give you a good idea of where to start.  Magento Theme Development Best Practices still apply.

For a good introductory tutorial, check out Nick Jones' post : [Introduction to Magento Theme Development](http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-magento-themes/)

For deeper understanding, I'd suggest Mastering Magento Theme Design from A[ndrea Saccà](https://github.com/andreasacca) and [Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/).  You can either

- Buy a [Hardcopy for Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/178328823X)
- Read it on [Safari Online](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mastering-magento-theme/9781783288236/)

This will work for CE 1.9+ but NOT CE 2.0

If you'd like to see a good example of a nice responsive custom Admin theme, check out the free Admin Responsive Theme from [Johann Reinke](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/7697/johann-reinke) via [Bubble Shop](https://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-admin-theme.html) .  They re-implemented the Magento 2 Responsive Theme as responsive 1.X Theme and it both looks and performs great.